# How to use REPLACE in a dynamic way

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I make the REPLACE function dynamic, by dynamic I mean that if for example one entry has 3 quotes and an other on has 5, I want it to cater for all situations

```
BEGIN TRAN
       update contacts
       set address1 = REPLACE(address1,'''','')
       where address1 like '%''''%'

ROLLBACK
```

Comment: I am guessing what you really are trying to do is replace any cases of multiple quotes with a single one? You can easily do this using the techniques from Jeff Moden [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/replace-multiple-spaces-with-one). Just replace the space with a quote and the concept is identical.

Comment: @SeanLange worked for me nearly! I just keep getting a extra space, `SELECT 
       --REPLACE(
              REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(  REPLACE(
                 LTRIM(RTRIM(address1))
                ,'''',' '+CHAR(50))  
            ,CHAR(50)+' ','')        
        ,CHAR(50)+'','''')  
        ,LTRIM(RTRIM(CHAR(50)))+'   ''','') AS CleanString 
   FROM contacts
 where address1 like '%''''%'`

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to just handle cases where the number of single quotes is 15 or less, you can use this pattern:

```
update contacts
    set address1 =    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                            REPLACE(
                                REPLACE(address1,'''''''''''''''''',''),  -- Replace any instance of eight quotes
                                '''''''''',''),                           -- Replace any instance of four quotes
                            '''''',''),                                   -- Replace any instance of two quotes
                        '''','')                                          -- Replace any single quote
where address1 like '%''''%'
```

If someone has entered more than 15 quotes into one field in sequence, you probably need to verify if they accidentally died while holding down the key.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for could be accomplished with a [CLR Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/dev-guide/clr-stored-procedures?view=sql-server-2014) written in dotnet. You can then use a regular expression to match and replace on the column(s) you want to correct.

There are a couple of things to keep in mind with this approach.

1. CLR procedures are a bit more complicated to create and update then just plain T-SQL.
2. You will loose parallelism, but if this is only run occasionally then it probably won’t matter.
3. They make debugging a bit more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Another non CLR option is to use a while loop. It won’t be very efficient as it will have to loop multiple times to remove any records that have more than one set of quotes to remove.

```
while (select count(*) from contacts where address1 like '%''''%') > 0
begin
BEGIN TRAN
       update contacts
       set address1 = REPLACE(address1,'''','')
       where address1 like '%''''%'

ROLLBACK
end
```

Comment: this nearly works except I need one quote to be left here, For example  Unit Egan'''''''''s should be Egan's